# What changes to netbeans or server configs do i need to make to allow my project to run php code properly

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, netbeans, runtime-error

I have a php file for the login page below. The username and password from the form on the connected html page are in the database but when I click submit I get the connection was reset error page. What am i missing? This was made in netbeans and I am using mysql server and apache web server. THere is also an attached logout option that selecting it just causes the browser to prompt for what to do with it (save or open). I have tried changing the values of userId and passID to values in the data base but it still does not work. What am i doing wrong? After some moving files around i got the message below.

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\DefaultWebsite\webroot\Loginpage.php on line 14 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\DefaultWebsite\webroot\Loginpage.php on line 15 Acess denied

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("dbconfig.php");
    $dbname="sailingdb";
    $errorvar = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST["pass"])) {
            $errorvar = "Both field are required";
        } else {
            //defining and injection protecting data
            $userID=$_POST['user'];
            $passID=$_POST["pass"];
            $userID=stripslashes($userID);
            $passID=stripslashes($passID);
            $userID=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbname, $userID);
            $passID=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbname, $passID);
            $passID=md5($passID);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users where userName = '$userID' AND pass = '$passID'";
            $queryresult=mysqli_query($dbname,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($queryresult)==1) {
                $_SESSION['userName'] = $userID;
                header("MainMenu.html");
            } else {
                header("MainMenu.html");
                echo "Acess denied";
            }
       }
    }
?>
```

The dbconfig.php code is below.

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $passw="*****";
    $dbname="Sailingdb";
    $conn=new mysqli($servername, $user, $passw, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Databse connection failed:    " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: dunno much about mysqli, but ReadingTFM suggests your mysqli_query function should pass the result of a connection object, not the database name.

Comment: Tried it as this   $queryresult=mysqli_query($query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC); Same result.

Comment: Err, was unclear... why do you even include 'dbconfig.php' if you are not using the connection object it creates ?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought the db connection came through the include.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The message says:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given

Since you have this in your dbconfig.php:

```
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $user, $passw, $dbname);
```

You may try to do it like that:

```
$userID=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userID);
$passID=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $passID);
```